# How can I begin to gain credibility within the scientific community without a degree?

Tags: communication

I'm working on a fairly extensive multidisciplinary research project - something a bit outside the purview of what would even be difficult for a respected field researcher to publish.

That being said, I am quite aware of my own biases, and I am double and triple checking my objectivity on a regular basis.

However - without a degree, I've found it extremely difficult to get anybody to simply review the work. The immediate response is to totally shut down.

What are some good steps to take? Even if it takes some time, I'm fine with that.

I just need to gain enough credibility to simply get a few reviews.

Comment: Work on a clear paragraph-length abstract of your work that is clear and understandable to someone with a background in your field. Once you have that, work on a page-length summary of your work. The goal is clarity; if I read either of these things and think you're trying to bullshit me with technobabble I will not want to read anything longer.

Comment: "Get anybody to simply review the work" is a difficult goal, without following the usual process of publishing and peer reviews (which requires the work being "ready for publication"), I doubt if it's possible for the vast majority of tenured academics to get anyone to "simply review the work" without having a personal or professional connection to them. It's not a matter of degrees, a random person with a degree (how would I even know that?) would be totally shut down as well unless I know of their previously published research work. It's not about credibility, but about an unusual request.

Comment: If this user is associated with the website of the same name, then it's clear that they have no credibility because their aims and beliefs are incredible.  https://phobostech.in/about-us/

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist - That is our site, and yes, we are painfully aware of how it sounds. Your reaction is among the mildest I've seen in response to "The AI STEM Drive" (what you're basically talking about).

I do not have academic credibility; true. But I am so utterly terrified of my own biases screwing this project up and wasting over 10 yrs. of study & almost 3 yrs. of full-time engagement now, that I continually invite others to listen to the researchcast and critique, rebut, analyze, respond, disprove ... whatever - anything and everything to help me keep my own biases in check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest that you read some papers related to what you are working on to see how your work compares. Try to develop a writing style that somewhat matches what you read.

Then, if you think your work is ready, submit it to a journal, such as the ones you've been reading. You will get some feedback. If the work clearly doesn't measure up, the feedback will be quick. But if it is more or less appropriate, you will get, after a while, some detailed comments on the work, and perhaps how you might improve it.

But the path to credibility runs through publications. The degree itself is less important other than to help an editor make a quick judgement.

Comment: Not only writing style, but formatting, fonts, display styles, bibliographic, and all other styles... at least until you are well-enough established that people will trust you _despite_ idiosyncrasies, etc.

Comment: Conferences may offer an opportunity to meet people and learn how they think and interact and how the "vibe" of the field is, so I would actually recommend conference papers first.